# ElGamal: different message with equal length random key

Tags: signature, elgamal-encryption

This situation applies to [ElGamal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ElGamal_encryption) digital signatures: consider messages m1 and m2 which we will encipher with a random key. The random key has the same [Hamming weight](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_weight). Is this situation secure? Why?

I have been unable to find more information about it.  Can we extract a message?

With reference to semantic security, could someone please describe the security situation when we encrypt messages using a key whose length is about the same as that of the messages?

Comment: Please elaborate and clarify your questions.  For example, what does your last sentence refer to?  And please make sure that the wording of the title reflects your question accurately.

Comment: I think there are several issues with this question, it first goes on about ElGamal digital signatures, and then about "message extraction" and encryption. Maybe that first mention of digsig was in error?

Comment: @ckwik  Please check that the edits have actually clarified your question(s).

Comment: _"digital signatures..encipher"_ that's two very different concepts. _"The random key has the same Hamming weight"_ Same Hamming weight as what?